# Creating Statistics of a SharePoint list

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, arraylist, web-parts

im completely new to SharePoint and C#, but i gotta do what im told right now :P

Currently i want to build a webpart that displays some statistics of project statusses.

We've built two lists:
One list for Projects
Another list for ProjectReports

ProjectReport contains a reference to Projects

We want to be able to display the following:

Number of Projects with Status RED: $x
Number of Projects with Status YELLOW: $x
Number of Projects with Status GREEN: $x

For this we need to only check the LATEST ProjectReport of all Project.

Current Idea:

- Go Through all ProjectStatus
- With each Status check if the current Project exists in an array
- Check if current Status is newer than the Status stored in the array
- if so, replace it, if not continue

Though i really get stuck at building the array i want. Personally i come from PHP and im really not fond of multidimensional arrays with different types :P

What i did:

```
ArrayList arrayItems = new ArrayList();
foreach(SPListItem item in allData) 
{
   if(arrayItems.Contains(item.GetFormattedValue("Name"))) {
     // later
   } else {
     // Here i need to create the new array, i want to store it like:
     //arrayItems.add("Name", "latestDate");
   }
}
```

As you can see, and its obvious to me, too, that ain't working. I'm just really stuck at figuring this thing out.

It'd be great if someone could just point me into the right direction. What do i have to search for, is this 'way of doing what i want to achieve' any good at all - is there a way easier solution that i simply don't know of?

Anyways, thanks in advance!

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would be much better off using an keyed collection construct such as a [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx).

Using your code:

```
        var cItems = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
        foreach (SPListItem item in allData)
        {
            string sName;
            DateTime dtDate;

            sName = item.GetFormattedValue("Name");
            dtDate = (DateTime)item.GetFormattedValue("latestDate");

            if (cItems.ContainsKey(sName))
            {
                // later
            }
            else
            {
                cItems.Add(sName, dtDate);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It's all a matter of knowing what's possible i guess. That's pretty much precicely what i need. Thanks a lot!